# Express JS - Unable to push array to table in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two tables in my MongoDB database.

1) User
2) Message

In my application, when a user creates a "message", I am attempting to insert the `messages` as an array to the `User` Table.

The Schemas defined for User and Messages are as shown below

**Message Scheme**

```
var schema = new Schema({
content: {type: String, required: true},
user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
```

**User Schema**

```
var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    messages: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'}]
});
```

I have a post method defined as shown below:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
User.findById(decoded.user._id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            title: 'An error occurred',
            error: err
        });
    }
    var message = new Message({
        content: req.body.content,
        user: user._id
    });
    console.log("Message:"+ message);
    message.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        user.messages.push(result);
        user.save();
        console.log('Saved...'+user);

        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Saved message',
            obj: result
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Here I first check if user exists and then insert the message sent into the "Message" table with `userid` reference and attempt to make a corresponding entry in the user table by pushing the Message into the column type that will accept messages as an array.

On running the application, in my console I can see the messages object attached to the user collection as shown below:

[image]

But when I check my database to see if the message is attached, it shows the message array as null:

[image]

Not sure where I am going wrong in attaching the array to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Make a minor change:

```
message.save(function (err, result) {
        // ... your other code 

        user.messages.push(result.id || result._id); // CHANGE THIS LINE
        user.save();
        console.log('Saved...'+user);

        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Saved message',
            obj: result
        });

    });
```

Comment: Hey Zeeshan , I tried your suggestion but it doesnt work. The message array in the User Collection is still empty

Comment: alright, what I suggested works on the version i have on my local machine, it means your problem was related to unstable/newer version but happy that your issue is resolved :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs Zeeshan .

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by updating the Schema for the User collection .

My Updated Schema is -

```
var schema = new Schema({
firstName: {type: String, required: true},
lastName: {type: String, required: true},
password: {type: String, required: true},
email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
messages: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'}]
```

},

```
{ usePushEach: true }, // ADDED THIS
);
```

**Reference :**

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5574#issuecomment-332290518
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5924